# How to predict the results of a tobit model (trained using AER library in R) with rpy2?

Tags: python, r, predict, rpy2

I have a tobit regression model in R working completely well, where I am also able to predict the actual output values for the test set using Inverse-Mills Ratio. However, the rest of the code for my project is in python so I wanted to explore and use the rpy2 API to migrate the code to python from R. I have been able to achieve the bit until model training using `AER.tobit()` from the library AER (used in R). However when it comes to predicting on test data, the code is not performing as expected. When I use `robjects.r.predict(model,newdata)` from rpy2, it just gives me fitted values for the training data instead of responses for the test data. If anybody knows a way around this and can let me know, it will be great help! Thanks in advance!

Let me know if you'd need more clarification on the problem.